# evt.preventDefault(); isn't working for dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, liquid

I have the following code that on click toggles a list to open/close. This works fine except when you click on a link within the list and the page refreshes the list doesn't remain open it closes.

I'm actually trying to get this to work in a Shopify theme so its hard for me to demonstrate whats happening. I think it might be the `evt.preventDefault();` not working after googling it but I'm not great with this so not entirely sure.

I tried to get a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/41grbf14/) working to demonstrate whats happing but couldn't replicate the problem.

If anyone has any suggestions what might be going wrong I would appreciate them.

JS

```
timber.sidebarSublist = function () {
  timber.cache.$sidebarSublistTrigger.on('click', function(evt) {
  var $el = $(this);

  evt.preventDefault();
  $el.toggleClass('is-active').next('.sidebar__sublist').slideToggle(200);
  });
};
```

Liquid

```
{% assign child_list_handle = link.title | handleize %}
{% if linklists[link.handle] == empty %}
  <li>
    <a href="{{ link.url }}" class="{% if link.url == active_url %} is-active{% endif %}">{{ link.title }}</a>
  </li>
{% else %}
  <li aria-haspopup="true">
    <a href="{{ link.url }}" class="sidebar__sublist-trigger sidebar-sublist__has-dropdown {% unless template == 'index' %}{% if link.url == active_url %} is-active{% endif %}{% endunless %}">
      {{ link.title }}
      <span class="icon-fallback-text sidebar__sublist-expand">
        <span class="icon icon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="fallback-text">+</span>
      </span>
      <span class="icon-fallback-text sidebar__sublist-contract">
        <span class="icon icon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="fallback-text">-</span>
      </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sidebar__sublist sidebar-sublist__content">
      {% for childlink in linklists[child_list_handle].links %}
          <li>
            <a href="{{ childlink.url }}">
              {{ childlink.title | escape }}</a>
          </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: if he page refreshes js will lose scope so it will be what when the first time the page was loaded unless you program it to save state using localStorage about the click event that happened to remain it opened or collapsed

Comment: Are you sure you've selected the element? You can `console.log()` something to rule out not having done so.

Comment: Wait, you want the page to expand the list **after** it's refreshed?

Comment: So I need to change what I'm telling it to do so that is saves the state for after the refresh?

Comment: No basically if the list is open and then a link within the list is clicked and the page refreshes to go to that link the list needs to remain open. Instead its reverting to its original state of display:none which is set in the CSS